# Change Set classpath:db/changelog/v-1.0/01-changeset-users-table.xml::2::vladislav_gil failed. Error: ERROR: the “users” relationship already exists

Tags: java, hibernate, liquibase

Ошибка: `Change Set classpath:db/changelog/v-1.0/01-changeset-users-table.xml::2::vladislav_gil failed. Error: ERROR: the “users” relationship already exists` . Проблема в том, что я и так знаю, что существует таблица USERS, но у меня в `application.properties` стоит `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate` Тогда почему эта ошибка всё равно появляется? Может, у меня sql-запрос неверный? Использую posgresql.

```
CREATE TABLE public.users
(
    id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
    email character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    first_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    last_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    password character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    role character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    status character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT uk_6dotkott2kjsp8vw4d0m25fb7 UNIQUE (email)
)

    TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.users
    OWNER to root;
```

[Ссылка](https://github.com/Blacit/HomeRent/tree/master/src/main/resources) на код, если не пригодится, то удалю.

```
2020-10-03 18:10:31.010 ERROR 11936 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet            : Change Set classpath:db/changelog/v-1.0/01-changeset-users-table.xml::2::vladislav_gil failed.  Error: ОШИБКА: отношение "users" уже существует [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE TABLE public.users
(
    id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
    email character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    first_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    last_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    password character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    role character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    status character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT uk_6dotkott2kjsp8vw4d0m25fb7 UNIQUE (email)
)

    TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.users
    OWNER to root]
2020-10-03 18:10:31.012  INFO 11936 --- [           main] l.lockservice.StandardLockService        : Successfully released change log lock
2020-10-03 18:10:31.014  WARN 11936 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set classpath:db/changelog/v-1.0/01-changeset-users-table.xml::2::vladislav_gil:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ОШИБКА: отношение "users" уже существует [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE TABLE public.users
(
    id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
    email character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    first_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    last_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    password character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    role character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    status character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT uk_6dotkott2kjsp8vw4d0m25fb7 UNIQUE (email)
)

    TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.users
    OWNER to root]
2020-10-03 18:10:31.014  INFO 11936 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-10-03 18:10:31.026  INFO 11936 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2020-10-03 18:10:31.029  INFO 11936 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-10-03 18:10:31.038  INFO 11936 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-10-03 18:10:31.044 ERROR 11936 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set classpath:db/changelog/v-1.0/01-changeset-users-table.xml::2::vladislav_gil:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ОШИБКА: отношение "users" уже существует [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE TABLE public.users
(
    id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
    email character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    first_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    last_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    password character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    role character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    status character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT uk_6dotkott2kjsp8vw4d0m25fb7 UNIQUE (email)
)

    TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.users
    OWNER to root]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1803) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at task.homerent.Application.main(Application.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set classpath:db/changelog/v-1.0/01-changeset-users-table.xml::2::vladislav_gil:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ОШИБКА: отношение "users" уже существует [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE TABLE public.users
(
    id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
    email character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    first_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    last_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    password character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    role character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    status character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT uk_6dotkott2kjsp8vw4d0m25fb7 UNIQUE (email)
)

    TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.users
    OWNER to root]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:646) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:53) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:83) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:202) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:366) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:314) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ОШИБКА: отношение "users" уже существует [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE TABLE public.users
(
    id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
    email character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    first_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    last_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    password character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    role character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    status character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT uk_6dotkott2kjsp8vw4d0m25fb7 UNIQUE (email)
)

    TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.users
    OWNER to root]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:402) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:59) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:131) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1273) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1255) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:609) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: отношение "users" уже существует
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:473) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:393) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:322) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:284) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:279) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:398) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Может в БД уже создана эта таблица?

Comment: @AlekseiGaile Да, она создана, именно так и есть. Только вот я сейчас создал новый проект, решил там запустить программу и мне пишет, что "отношение "public.house" не существует". Соответственно, я даже не понимаю в чём проблема в связи с этим.

Comment: я имею ввиду что она создана до применения миграции.

Comment: @AlekseiGaile я обновил прошлый комментарий. Да, была создана до миграции

Comment: дропните всю БД и пусть миграция пройдет с нуля

Comment: Если вы управляете миграциями с помощью liquibase, то не надо лезть самому в БД, все должно быть описано в ченьжлогах

Comment: 1. Дропнул 2. в application.properties сделал validate. 3. Создалось 3 таблицы, две databasechangelog, databasechangeloglock и users. 4.  ОШИБКА: отношение "house" не существует 5. Больше ничего нового не создаётся.

Comment: предполагаю что до таблицы контракт должна быть создана таблица Хаус, потому что что контракт ссылается на нее. А до Хауса должна быть Сити, т.к. Хаус ссылается на нее

Comment: Поменял всё местами, ошибка пропала, появилась новая, пишите, пожалуйста, сюда свой ответ о том, что необходимо таблицу создавать в самой миграции, а не до. Я пока что новый вопрос создам, тут каскад ошибок

Comment: @AlekseiGaile вопросов больше не будет, спасибо большое за помощь) Я потратил на это целый день, действительно, нужно создавать в определённой последовательности файлы, чтобы они могли свои ключи настроить. Пожалуйста, укажите этот момент в ответе, чтобы люди об этом знали. При условии, что записи связаны между собой и столбцы тоже*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

liquibase создает таблицы последовательно проходя по changelog, соответственно нужно создавать таблицы в правильном порядке. Сначала независимые таблицы, потом те которые имеют связи с независимыми.

К примеру, нельзя сначала написать insert данных в таблицу, а в следующем changeset создать таблицу.