# Error Reading Migration File: class path resource [db/changelogs/db.changelog-master.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, liquibase

Не понимаю чем ему путь не устраивает, всё ведь верно прописано.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

liquibase.properties

```
classpath=
changeLogFile= db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/new
username= root
password= 123
driver= org.postgresql.Driver
```

pom.xml

org.liquibase
liquibase-maven-plugin
3.6.3

db.changelog-master.xml

```
<changeSet id="0" author="blacit">
        <tagDatabase tag="db_init"/>
    </changeSet>

    <include file="v-1.0/db.changelog-v.1.0.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>

    <changeSet id="7" author="blacit">
        <tagDatabase tag="v.1.0"/>
    </changeSet>
                    <propertyFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: Error Reading Migration File: class path resource [db/changelog/v-1.0/01-changeset-users.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1803) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at task.homerent.Application.main(Application.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: Error Reading Migration File: class path resource [db/changelog/v-1.0/01-changeset-users.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:25) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:217) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:190) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:366) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:314) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.SetupException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: Error Reading Migration File: class path resource [db/changelog/v-1.0/01-changeset-users.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.handleChildNode(DatabaseChangeLog.java:359) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.load(DatabaseChangeLog.java:308) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:23) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: Error Reading Migration File: class path resource [db/changelog/v-1.0/01-changeset-users.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:25) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.include(DatabaseChangeLog.java:568) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.handleChildNode(DatabaseChangeLog.java:351) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.SetupException: Error Reading Migration File: class path resource [db/changelog/v-1.0/01-changeset-users.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.handleChildNode(DatabaseChangeLog.java:359) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.load(DatabaseChangeLog.java:308) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:23) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Error Reading Migration File: class path resource [db/changelog/v-1.0/01-changeset-users.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parseToNode(XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java:118) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:15) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.include(DatabaseChangeLog.java:568) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.handleChildNode(DatabaseChangeLog.java:351) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [db/changelog/v-1.0/01-changeset-users.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:195) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase$SpringResourceOpener.getResourcesAsStream(SpringLiquibase.java:613) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.util.StreamUtil.singleInputStream(StreamUtil.java:186) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parseToNode(XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java:71) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.0.jar:na]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Comment: db/changelog/v-1.0/01-changeset-users.xml , а название файла другое - 01-changeset-users-table.xml

Comment: db/changelog/v-1.0/ - это ведь путь, а название 01-changeset-users-table.xml. Что-то я отличия не замечаю. Заметил

Comment: Error Reading Migration File: class path resource [db/changelog/v-1.0/01-changeset-users.xml]

Comment: что-то очень странное творится. Он мне показывал эту ошибку, потом убрал table, он начал говорить, что table снова не хватает в названиях, я их поставил и теперь вот эту ошибку высвечивает: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1185650/change-set-classpathdb-changelog-v-1-0-01-changeset-users-table-xml2vladisl

Comment: По этому вопросу вы правы. Да, я версию не ту загрузил с гита. Сейчас актуальная проблема по ссылке выше. Если можете, то укажите здесь в ответе, что путь некорректный был, потому что не так много ответов на этот вопрос, так ещё и на русскоязычном стеке будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Некорректный путь к файлу - Error Reading Migration File: class path resource [db/changelog/v-1.0/01-changeset-users.xml]

db/changelog/v-1.0/01-changeset-users.xml , а название файла другое - 01-changeset-users-table.xml